# Communication between methods javafx

Tags: javafx

I have a method in firstcontroller like
public void getSum(){
some codes here ...
}
and a method in the secondcontroller like
public void Addsomething(){
some code here ...
}
I want to call the firstcontroller method getSum() in the secondcontroller to update some values in the firstcontroller when I use the secondcontroller method Addsomething(),to update some values in firstcontroller according to getSum() method. hope it' clear ,and thanks

Comment: JavaFX is just Java; you call methods the same way you call methods in any other Java code: `objectReference.methodName(...)`. However, in a well-designed UI application, controllers should not have references to each other.

Answer (score 1):

The methods you mentioned sound like beeing some kind of business logic and thus belong into a model class but not into any controller class. Before you start writing GUI code you should first learn the basics of GUI/model separation concepts (like MVC, MVVM, ...). Once you have understood these concepts the question you have asked will just vanish.